# Solidity Formatting In VSCode

Tags: solidity, web3js, visual-studio-code

### Hello everyone! Sorry for such a trivial question but after spending all day solving a pointless task I decided to ask smarter people

The problem is simple.

**I have a solidity extension by Juan Blanco in vscode for writing smart contracts.
Writing smart contracts I noticed that it has some printWidth limits and if the line has more than 80-100 symbols it wraps into the next line. From the beginning, it looked OK but after a while, I realised that it's quite annoying because more than half of a file is just empty.**
[image]
[image]

**My settings in vscode for formatting.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**I even have .prettierignore file to ignore small printwidth just in case.**
[image]

But it still doesn't work.

**The only variant when I can get normal formatting is to use format document(forced) in vscode**
[image]

**And the result will be**
[image]

**But after pressing ctrl+s it resets all formatting.**

I hope I gave enough screens and info and I would be really grateful if you know how to solve such a simple problem because I gave up

Comment: Did you ever get answer to this?

Comment: Nop, still waiting :D @GGzmos

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble getting Format on Save to work but eventually got it working using the following steps.

Install the following two extensions:-

Solidity By Juan Blanco

[image]

Prettier Code Formatter
[image]

( I couldn't get the format on save to work with Solidity by the Nomic Foundation)

Then in settings (CTRL ,) type in

Format on Save

(Make sure you have this enabled if it isn't already)

[image]

Then still in settings type in

Solidity Formatter

Set it to Prettier Code Formatter (esbenp.prettier-vscode)

[image]

The final setting is changing Solidity Formatter to Prettier (default is none)

[image]

I had settings in .prettier and .settings and I just removed them and solidity files formatted when I hit save.

Answer (score 0):

For me the  problem was solved by using [Forge formatter](https://lib.rs/crates/forge-fmt).
You probably need to install [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/) and [integrate it with your vscode IDE](https://book.getfoundry.sh/config/vscode).

My vscode settings:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[solidity]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "JuanBlanco.solidity"
},
"solidity.formatter": "forge",
```

It does not break my long lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my vscode settings that worked for the Hardhat Solidity Extension (also requires prettier):

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[solidity]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "NomicFoundation.hardhat-solidity"
  },
  "solidity.formatter": "prettier"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I tried the online solution, which was configuring ".setting.json", but it didn't work. But I happened to come across a way that works:

step 1: Install solidity and prettier plugins.

step 2: Configer the default formatter: prettier
[image]

step 3: Create ".prettierrc" file in the project root, the content:

```
{
 "printWidth": 1000
}
```

Hope this helps you.